# Sum numbers in an array

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a Python newbie.

At this [site](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sum_and_product_of_array#Python), they show how to sum list of integers.

What if instead of a list of raw ints, you had a list of

```
class Number :
   def __init__( self, x = 0) :
      self.number = x      

   def getNumber( self ) :
      return self.number
```

What's the Python code to sum the self.number in an array in a few lines (hopefully)?

Comment: Thank you all for pointing out my mistake of array and list. Fixed.

Answer (score 6):

I am assuming you mean a list or maybe another kind of iterable:

`sum(x.getNumber() for x in L)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sum(x.getNumber() for x in l)
```

By the way, `[1, 2, 3]`is a *list*, not an array.

Answer (score 1):

Use a generator or list comprehension:

```
numbers = [Number(1), Number(2)]
sum(n.getNumber() for n in numbers)
```

Simply, it calls the method `getNumber()` on each item before summing.

Answer (score -1):

Here are several ways to do it:

```
sum( e.getNumber() for e in L )

sum( e.number for e in L )

reduce( lambda a,b: a + b.getNumber(), L, 0 )  # likewise for e.number
```

Comment: geez, thanks for the attitude. But I will thank you anyway for showing me a few different ways to solve the problem.

Comment: hold on, should the last one not be `lambda x,e: x+e.getNumber(),L,0` ?

Comment: what if it's python 3.0, can we use something else instead of reduce()? See: http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196

Comment: @ShaChris23 We still have reduce in Python 3, but is in functools module. So use `functools.reduce()` instead. But knowing the `reduce` concept is still nice. It is somewhat (but not totally) related to `MapReduce`, which you are supposed to know if you are a software engineer.

Comment: Adding a positive vote since the sarcasm has already been removed, to be fair to you. Still your lowest-scoring answer though :P